# How to properly use MultiByteToWideChar

Tags: c++, windows, msdn, wstring, multibyte-functions

I am using MultiByteToWideChar to convert my string to a wstring. I am first trying to get the required size for my wstring. According to the documentation passing 0 as the last argument should accomplish this. Using `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_COMPOSITE, str.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0);` returns 0 as the required size of the wstring buffer. I have verified that str is a non empty string as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If the function returns 0, you need to call GetLastError to get the error code.  What error code is returned?

Comment: Is `str` properly UTF-8 encoded, or might it be in a different encoding?

Comment: It is an error return.  Always assert() such values, use  GetLastError() to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> For UTF-8 or code page 54936 (GB18030, starting with Windows Vista), dwFlags must be set to either 0 or MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS. Otherwise, the function fails with ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS.

You're using CP_UTF8 but also passing the MB_COMPOSITE flag, so that's why it's failing.